# ODBC driver is missing

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I am using microsoft office 365 pro plus  (2016)

I am trying to install Microsoft access driver *.accbd in ODBC data source administrtor.

I installed Micorsoft access database engine 2016 , After that i can see the driver .mdb but not the .accdb

I went to C:\windows\syswow64 and ran the odbcad32 as an administrtor but even though the .accdb is not listed.

What else i can do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out that the .accdb drivers installed on system32 folder. So when i access the odbc data source manager from system32 folder then it works.

I still do not know how i can have them on SysWOW64 folder.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not able to add comment to your answer, so i'll post it as an "answer".

There are two versions of odbc administrator on windows 7 and up, 32bit and 64bit, 
you may need to make sure the right one is running, depends on your OS.

take a look here,
https://www.yellowfinbi.com/resources/forum/yfforum-how-do-i-setup-the-dsn-for-microsoft-access-odbc-driver-thread-103711